# Reading/Printing special characters in C

Tags: c, windows, printf, fgets, wchar-t

I have Win11 and winlibs personal build version gcc-12.2.0-llvm-15.0.7-mingw-w64ucrt-10.0.0-r4. Im trying to read special croatian letters (č,ć,š,đ,ž) from stdin but program converts them to regular english letters (c,c,s,d,z).

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int main() {
    wchar_t line[MAXLINE];
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "hr_HR.UTF-8");

    printf("Enter a line of text:\n");

    if (fgetws(line, MAXLINE, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Error reading input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    wprintf(L"You entered: %ls", line);

    return 0;
}
```

Input and output:

Enter a line of text:
šđčćžasd
You entered: sdcczasd

Please, tell me what is the problem? Could it be due to compilers for windows. I tried to compile it with gcc and clang.

Comment: On Windows, you need to change the file mode of `stding` and `stdout`. See the example at the bottom of the [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-170) .

Comment: @LukaIllich "tell me what is the problem?" --> Next time, with such issues, good to report the return value of `setlocale(LC_ALL, "hr_HR.UTF-8");`